# How to get current url and base url in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, url-rewriting

Now im working on a project, but i can't get current url or base url in react.
i need to get url and base url in react for active open tab when im in specific route.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an 
attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical 
problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result,
 we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt 
and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: Assuming you're not using a router such as react-router. Just use `window.location.href`

Comment: Get base url using: **window.location.origin**

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the active url and some other informations about location in your component through his props :

```
this.props.match
```

or `props.match` if you use functional components

Answer (score 1):

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp):

> - `window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page
> - `window.location.hostname` returns the domain name of the web host
> - `window.location.pathname` returns the path and filename of the current page

This also works in React.